# write error: No space left on device in embedded linux

Tags: linux, system, embed

all
  I have a embedded board, run linux OS. and I use yaffs2 as rootfs.
  I run a program on it, but after some times, it got a error "error No space left on device.". but I checked the flash, there still have a lot free space. 
  I just write some config file. the config file is rarely update. the program will write some log to flash. log size is limited to 2M.
  I don't know why, and how to solve. 
  Help me please!(my first language is not English,sorry. hope you understand what I say)

some debug info:

```
    # ./write_test 
    version 1.0
    close file :: No space left on device
    return errno 28
    # cat /proc/yaffs 
    YAFFS built:Nov 23 2015 16:57:34


    Device 0 "rootfs"
    start_block........... 0
    end_block............. 511
    total_bytes_per_chunk. 2048
    use_nand_ecc.......... 1
    no_tags_ecc........... 1
    is_yaffs2............. 1
    inband_tags........... 0
    empty_lost_n_found.... 0
    disable_lazy_load..... 0
    refresh_period........ 500
    n_caches.............. 10
    n_reserved_blocks..... 5
    always_check_erased... 0
    data_bytes_per_chunk.. 2048
    chunk_grp_bits........ 0
    chunk_grp_size........ 1
    n_erased_blocks....... 366
    blocks_in_checkpt..... 0

    n_tnodes.............. 749
    n_obj................. 477
    n_free_chunks......... 23579

    n_page_writes......... 6092
    n_page_reads.......... 11524
    n_erasures............ 96
    n_gc_copies........... 5490
    all_gcs............... 1136
    passive_gc_count...... 1136
    oldest_dirty_gc_count. 95
    n_gc_blocks........... 96
    bg_gcs................ 96
    n_retired_writes...... 0
    n_retired_blocks...... 0
    n_ecc_fixed........... 0
    n_ecc_unfixed......... 0
    n_tags_ecc_fixed...... 0
    n_tags_ecc_unfixed.... 0
    cache_hits............ 0
    n_deleted_files....... 0
    n_unlinked_files...... 289
    refresh_count......... 1
    n_bg_deletions........ 0

    Device 2 "data"
    start_block........... 0
    end_block............. 927
    total_bytes_per_chunk. 2048
    use_nand_ecc.......... 1
    no_tags_ecc........... 1
    is_yaffs2............. 1
    inband_tags........... 0
    empty_lost_n_found.... 0
    disable_lazy_load..... 0
    refresh_period........ 500
    n_caches.............. 10
    n_reserved_blocks..... 5
    always_check_erased... 0
    data_bytes_per_chunk.. 2048
    chunk_grp_bits........ 0
    chunk_grp_size........ 1
    n_erased_blocks....... 10
    blocks_in_checkpt..... 0

    n_tnodes.............. 4211
    n_obj................. 24
    n_free_chunks......... 658

    n_page_writes......... 430
    n_page_reads.......... 467
    n_erasures............ 7
    n_gc_copies........... 421
    all_gcs............... 20
    passive_gc_count...... 13
    oldest_dirty_gc_count. 3
    n_gc_blocks........... 6
    bg_gcs................ 4
    n_retired_writes...... 0
    n_retired_blocks...... 0
    n_ecc_fixed........... 0
    n_ecc_unfixed......... 0
    n_tags_ecc_fixed...... 0
    n_tags_ecc_unfixed.... 0
    cache_hits............ 0
    n_deleted_files....... 0
    n_unlinked_files...... 2
    refresh_count......... 1
    n_bg_deletions........ 0
    #
```

log and config file stored in "data". 
thanks!!

Comment: There are more types of "space" than just inodes, especially on embedded filesystems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In General this could be your disk space (here Flash), first of all check your flash space with with df -h (or other commands you have.. df is present in BusyBox). But if your flash space (specially on your program partition) is ok, this could be your "inode" (directory) space problem, you could see your inode usage with df -i command.
 (a good link for this: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Knowledge_Base:No_space_left_on_device_while_there_is_plenty_of_space_available)

If non of these is the problem cause, I think you have to have a deeper look at your code, specially if you deal with disk I/O!
Also good to mention that be aware of memory & heap space & free all allocated spaces in you functions.